# App Inventor WebView AFTER Web Post

Tags: android, post, web, webview, app-inventor

I want to connect my App Inventor App to a website, through the `web` component with a `post` request. Now, I want to open a `webview` of the same webpage, with the same `POST` data that I used with the `web` component.

[My Blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yGvy.png)
[image]

The webpage is loaded with HTML (like head, body, divs, spans), and what I want is to save that HTML code to a file, and then use the WebView with THAT `.html` file. For some reason, I always get a blank screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a blank page, because the `file` component works asynchronously, which means, the `webviewer` component is trying to access the file before saving of the file is finished. You therefore should access the webpage in the `File.AfterFileSaved` event instead.

Btw. a simpler method (without using the `file` component) would be to save the file directly using the `web` component, see also 
[How to download a file and save it on your device](https://puravidaapps.com/filedownload.php)